# Вывод текста на страницу с периодичностью

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть скрипт:

```
$text = 39;
if( $text <= 50 ) {
    echo "<div style='border: 1px solid black;'>У вас еще есть время</div>";
}
```

Как выводить этот текст каждые 5 секунд?

```
$text = 39;
if( $text <= 50 ) {
    echo "<div style='border: 1px solid black;'>У вас еще есть время</div>";
    echo "<div style='border: 1px solid black;'>У вас еще есть время</div>";
    echo "<div style='border: 1px solid black;'>У вас еще есть время</div>";
    // и так далее...
}
```

Нужно, наверное, использовать конструкцию while, но тогда скрипт просто выводит текст на экран, пока не кончится память.

Comment: а где у вас в коде счётчик ?

Comment: @Arsen, $text постоянно обновляется, я сделал его статичным, чтобы вопрос был понятнее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А какой смысл это делать через PHP? Намного проще это реализовать на клиенте, через JavaScript. Например:

```
function timer_function() {
    var count = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById('root_container_id').insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<div style='border: 1px solid black;'>У вас еще есть время</div>' );
        count++;
        if (count >= 50) clearInterval(timer);
    }, 5000);

}
```

Добавляем содержимое к уже существующему через insertAdjacentHTML (вставляем после того кода, который уже есть). Надо будет назначить родительскому контейнеру id="root_container_id". По завершению условий (cond_end) - прекращаем выполнение цикла.

Не забываем помести код в обработчик, чтобы он начал выполняться сразу после загрузки страницы:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    timer_function();
});
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59794/discussion-on-answer-by-dmitry-maslennikov------).